# [class]:hover working but [class] not working in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of CSS that I'm using to create a button in a table. The table is generated via a PHP query, and the button is within a cell in one of the generated table rows. When applying CSS to the button however, the :hover part it works and shows the CSS, but when I don't hover over it, the normal class doesn't work, i.e. it just shows the default icon with no CSS applied to it.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #5FB0FF;
  /* Blue background */
  border: none;
  /* Remove borders */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /* Some padding */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Mouse pointer on hover */
}


/* Darker background on mouse-over */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
```

```html
echo '<td><a href="php_files/PatientEdit.php?
Patient_ID=$res[Patient_ID]\">Edit</a> | <a 
href="../includes/DeletePatient.inc.php?Patient_ID=$res[Patient_ID]\" 
onClick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete? ")">
Delete</a><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></button></td>';
```

Comment: Seems to me its working as it should be form the given code.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect it with the FF or Chrome dev tools. Is the class applied to the button?

Comment: In snippet code it seems to work as expected. Can you modify the code further, may be add some text (or icon as you mentioned). The problem could be due to some other CSS in your project interfering with the CSS you have written here.

Comment: Someone edited the post and removed the echo/php parts of it. In the snippet it works, but when its within an echo surrounded by ' ' it doesn't work

Comment: The fact its being echoed does not change anything. Problem is not in code presented. Use DEV tools to see why CSS is not being applied. Its all there.

Comment: Here's the Pastebin php/html: https://pastebin.com/uHAnhMf1   and css: https://pastebin.com/wu7kvE3N

Comment: The echo/php parts are irrelevant, because PHP runs on the server and sends the _output_, those things that are _echoed_, to the browser. By the time the browser is acting on the markup with the CSS the PHP effectively no longer exists. It was edited to make it into a runnable stack-snippet. With the `echo` added back it is no longer valid.

Comment: There was a part of css that interfered with the button, I changed btn to btn1 and the CSS showed up properly. Thanks @SachinSingh for the suggestion